# how to write a script that runs on the beaglebone

Tags: scripts, beagleboard

I was wondering how can I write a script that execute commands on the beaglebone.

my script looks like this:

```
ssh debian@192.168.7.2
mkdir folder1/
mkdir folder2/folder3
```

but it always stops after the first line and puts me into the terminal of the BB?

How do I get it to run the other two commands on it ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to run those two commands inside the SSH session on `192.168.7.2`, you just have to pass the commands as parameters to the `ssh` command:

```
ssh debian@192.168.7.2 'mkdir folder1/; mkdir folder2/folder3'
```

Notice the quotes around the commands, and the semicolon between them.

However, in this case, you can call `mkdir` once and pass it both folders to create; and, just in case `folder2` doesn't already exist, you should pass `mkdir` the `-p` switch to create it if needed.

```
ssh debian@192.168.7.2 'mkdir -p folder1/ folder2/folder3'
```

Hope this helps!

PS, for reference you should read the man pages for [ssh](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh.1?query=ssh&sec=1) and [mkdir](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir)

Answer (score 2):

You can run commands on the remote computer's shell non-interactively using `ssh`. The syntax is:

```
ssh user@destination 'command_1; command_2 .....'
```

replace `;` with `&&` to run a command depending on the success of the preceding one.

So, you can do:

```
ssh debian@192.168.7.2 'mkdir -p folder1/ folder2/folder3'
```

Note that the directories will be created under the home directory of user `debian`.

The non-interactive session will be terminated once the `mkdir` command returns.